# How can I see my full PCA data on the ordination map? and how can I change geom point colors of my data in R?

Tags: r, plot, pca, vegan

I am using a package called Vegan to calculate the PCA of my environmental samples and then plot my PCA values on the ordination space in R, I am using the data from an excel sheet where certain columns are chosen for the PCA calculation as below:

```
library(vegan)
library("readxl")
library(devtools)

SRSummer21 <- read_excel(file.choose())


SRSummer21PCA <- rda(SRSummer21[,c(3:17)], scale = TRUE)

summary(SRSummer21PCA)

ordiplot (SRSummer21PCA, display = 'species', type = 't')

ef <- envfit (SRSummer21PCA, SRSummer21[,c(41:43)])

plot (ef)
```

I try to add 3 other variables on top of the PCA calculation, as I don't want them to be in the original calculation, they are "Alkalinity", "Conductivity", and "pH", which are in columns 41 to 43 in my datasheet. Now when I plot the data, it gives me a simple plot with a set of black geom points as my data, however, I can't completely see the arrows of the data I added on top, I need to fit in the image so that all data and arrows can be seen in the space, I also like to change the shape and color of my data points according to their "Treatment" which is either of 3 different values: Cold, Moderate, Warm, which are written in column "Treatment" of my excel datasheet. you can see that part of the alkalinity arrow is present but the rest I can't see

Does anyone know how I can do this?

Thanks[image: R plot showing part of the data]

Comment: See this recent Question and Answer for how to extract various elements and use `ggplot` to plot them with more control. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71906621/plotting-a-subset-of-envfit-results-onto-an-ordination

Comment: Your data points seem to be on the unit circle (which can happen when you have data with low dimensionality and use correlations, as with `scale = TRUE`), whereas your extra variables are not. You must set the scaling of your axis so that you can show the observations you later add. In `ordiplot` this happens with arguments `xlim`, `ylim`.

Comment: @JariOksanen Thanks a lot! I managed to fit all data now in the plot, do you know perhaps how to add axis label as well? (especially I want to see what is the PCA score for PC1 for example and have it written on the axis) Thanks!

Comment: `xlab`, `ylab` comands should work.